# SignalR : What's the equivalent of 'NetworkCredential("user", "password")' in JavaScript?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, .net, signalr

In SignalR for a basic Authentication, there is this function in .Net Client:

```
 var hubConnection = new HubConnection("http://localhost:8080/signalr");
 hubConnection.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("user", "password");
```

With these credentials, we can send the login and password to the signalR server.

What's the equivalent in JavaScript client?

I tested this, but didn't work :

```
$.connection.hub.url = "http://localhost:8080/signalr";
$.connection.hub.qs = { name : "user", password : "password" };
```

Thanks!

Comment: As far as I know, this doesn't exist.. and the reason should be obvious.. how secure is it to have this be in client-side javascript?  All you have to do is view source and you see the servers username and password!

Comment: Yes, I agree with you for the security, but it's like the html form with login password, they don't exist anymore after validation.

Answer (score -2):

just try to create a Dart wrapper around the existing JS library.

Read :

[Creating a wrapper js class for consuming signalr services.](http://www.layoric.org/2014/07/dartjavascript-interop-creating-signalr.html)

Comment: heuu, I need to use the signalr javascript API, and there is no documentation aubout this :/